# How to get user thumbnails from comments feed in one request on YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm getting comments feed from YouTube. There is an author property with uri parameter. How can I get authors thumbnails without making multiple requests to get every author's thumbnail?
Can I use something like that (I mean "fields" parameter):
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/j9-xvIK3WNM/comments?alt=json&fields=entry(published,content,author(uri))

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in v2 of the API using batch processing: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing

This previous question has a sample batch processing request for obtaining channel profile info: [Youtube API Batch Request BUG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052959/youtube-api-batch-request-bug)

**But**, you need to be able to do a HTTP `POST`, and since you appear to be working JavaScript, that's a problem for browsers that don't support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).